# Function to convert List to Dictionary and viceversa using Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a function that will convert a dictionary to a list (with dictionary key as the first value in the list) and a list back to a dictionary. 
For example, given

```
dict1 = {'a':[1,2], 'b':[3], 'c':[4,5]},
```

the function should return an answer:

```
[['a', 1, 2], ['c', 4, 5], ['b', 3]].
```

Alternatively, if the input is

```
lst1 = [['a', 1, 2], ['c', 4, 5], ['b', 3]],
```

then the function should return:

```
{'a':[1,2], 'b':[3], 'c':[4,5]}
```

I have written the following code. It is doing what it is supposed to do except for one problem. If the input is a dictionary, it returns

```
[['a', [1, 2]], ['c', [4, 5]], ['b', [3]]] (a nested list) instead of
[['a', 1, 2], ['c', 4, 5], ['b', 3]].
```

My Function Code:

```
def convertDL(value1):
   if type(value1) == dict:
       scoreList = []
       for key, value in value1.items():
           temp = [key, value]
           scoreList.append(temp)
       return scoreList
   if type(value1) == list:
       scoreDict = {}
       i = 0
       for item in value1:
           scoreDict[value1[i][0]] = value1[i][1:]
           i = i +1
       return scoreDict
convertDL(lst1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions and dict comprehensions do the work for you:

```
lst1 = [[k] + v for k, v in dct1.iteritems()]
```

and

```
dct1 = {v[0]: v[1:] for v in lst1}
```

or, as a function:

```
def convertDL(val):
    if isinstance(val, dict):
        return [[k] + v for k, v in val.iteritems()]
    return {v[0]: v[1:] for v in val}
```

Use `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()` if you are using Python 3.

Demo:

```
>>> def convertDL(val):
...     if isinstance(val, dict):
...         return [[k] + v for k, v in val.iteritems()]
...     return {v[0]: v[1:] for v in val}
... 
>>> convertDL({'a':[1,2], 'b':[3], 'c':[4,5]})
[['a', 1, 2], ['c', 4, 5], ['b', 3]]
>>> convertDL([['a', 1, 2], ['c', 4, 5], ['b', 3]])
{'a': [1, 2], 'c': [4, 5], 'b': [3]}
```